# New ubuntu user with 18.04.3 systyem OS 32-bit

Tags: 64-bit, intel, samsung

I want to attempt to change from my 32-bit OS system to a 64-bit OS what should I do? What is best way to do it? Where can I get more information?

Comment: To switch from 32bit (x86) to 64bit (amd64 or x86_64) you need to re-install.  Your data files are okay (ie. don't need change), so you could use Manual Partitioning (or *something else*) and opt not to format your partitions; it'll cause system directories to be erased, then system installed, then your old apps added back (if available).

Comment: fyi:  x86 was created by intel, intel though tried to get the market to move to an incompatible 64bit format (ia64), which lost out to the x86 compatible amd64; ia64 is now a historical footnote, thus why amd64 works for AMD or Intel 64bit x86_64; it's not AMD only.  Unless you've got a museum age intel ia64 computer; you want amd64 (*ignoring ARM & other Power architectures*).

Comment: I don't know why you tagged samsung; I opted to read the 'intel' to mean x86 32bit to 64bit, rather than samsung which do make ARM based devices which can also be moved from 32bit to 64bit.  The same applies regardless of processor architecture (ie. you must re-install).

Answer (score 1):

32-bit and 64-bit are different architectures, so a re-install is required.

*I've also assumed you mean x86 (i386/i686 32-bit) moving to x86_64 or *amd64* (64-bit), and not ARM 32-bit to 64-bit move, or PowerPC 32-bit to 64-bit, but same would apply - you need to re-install*

You should backup your data and then re-install.

Your user settings, and user files will work without change once the new system is installed. You should replace your existing system, but do not select an option that formats unless you've safely backed up your data.

Myself I'd use *Manual Partitioning* or *Something else* options to ensure you don't format, which will

- take note of your installed (added post-install) packages
- erase system directories, and install system
- re-add back (if available) your additional packages
- request you to reboot

You've tagged 'intel', which is *amd64* for 64-bit.  The x86 architecture was created by intel; but intel tried to move the market to an incompatible 64-bit format (ia64), but market forces wanted compatibility, so AMD's x86_64 compatible processors won out. ia64 is now a historical footnote, and *amd64* applies to AMD or Intel 64bit x86_64 cpus.